# Why can't I pipe 'where' output to 'type' in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipeline

I'm trying to print the contents of a batch file that exists in my path.

I can find the file with 'where':

```
> where myscript
C:\scripts\myscript.bat
```

I can display the contents of the file with 'type':

```
> type C:\scripts\myscript.bat
echo This is my script. There are many like it, but this one is mine.
```

However, when I want to be lazy and use a single command:

```
> where myscript | type
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Based on some tests I did, it seems 'where' output can't be piped out and 'type' input can't be piped in.

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work in this way?

P.S. I was able to do this in Powershell: `Get-Command myscript | Get-Content`.

Comment: The filename is an argument to `type`, it doesn't come through standard input. Piping connects one processes standard input to another's standard output.

Comment: So a variable is the only way to pass the data into 'type'?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's certainly an option - you could use `set` to set a variable based on piped input. You'd probably get better answers on Super User than here on Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Luaan said in the comments, `type` will only accept the filename as argument and not via its input channel. So piping won't do the trick in your case. You'll have to use another way to give the result of the `where` command as an argument. Fortunately the [`for /f`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) can help you process outputs of other commands. To print the file corresponding to the output of the `where` command you'll have to use this on the command line:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %G IN ('where myscript') DO type "%G"
```

In a batch-file you'll have to use

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('where myscript') DO type "%%G"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks to you and @Luaan for your explanations.

Answer (score 2):

As exposed by Luaan and J.Baoby, not all the commands can retrieve its arguments from a pipe or a redirection, but some of them can.

Certainly not the exact output, but probably the nearer syntax in command line

```dos
where myScript | findstr /f:/ "^"
```

The output of the `where` command is piped into a `findstr`. The `/f` switch is used to indicate the list of files to be searched, and the slash means that the list will be readed from standard input. The `"^"` is just a regular expression that will match all the lines in the files enumerated by the `where` comamnd